# Java -Reactive Programming vs Event Listener

Tags: java, reactive-programming

How the Reactive Programming differs from calling a function in Event listener (mouse, key), because both are kind of asynchronous event stream so whats the advantage of Reactive over traditional Event listeners calls?

Comment: How it is duplicate when the linked question is java *script*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event listener has actually only a subset of the functionalities provided by [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki), and that's exactly the problem that it tries to solve:

But let's back up a few steps, it's easier to understand what an [Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) is if you compare it to an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) (push vs. pull).

`Iterator.next()` is equivalent to `Observable.onNext()` - when the next item/event occurs - consume it.

`Iterator.hasNext()` is equivalent to `Observable.onComplete()` - it allows the publisher to notify the subscriber that there are no more events to consume (one thing that was missing in the EventListener model).

For the third, `Observable.onError()` there is no equivalent, because with Iterator, when you try to get `next()` or `remove()` you know that you might get `NoSuchElementException`, `UnsupportedOperationException` or `IllegalStateException` and you can catch and handle any of them since you're doing it synchronously.

For the publisher, if an error occurs there is no way to notify the Listener/subscriber other then to crash. `onError()` is the last missing part that was made so that the Observable can enable a graceful handling of any error.

To sum up, Reactive Java came to fix parts that were missing from the event model for a long time. By providing those missing parts, and by providing a functional programming style (supports map, flatmap, filter etc) it helps composing async calls in a natural, readable way reducing boilerplate-code that is necessary when the programming style is imperative (e.g. nested for-loops) and which creates the [callback-hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402376/how-to-compose-observables-to-avoid-the-given-nested-and-dependent-callbacks).

Comment: informative thanks, can you suggest some site to get start the Reactive Programming.

Comment: @jerith2 the first two links in my answer would be a good start!