# RxJava - Nested Observables? (Retrofit)

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I'm facing the problem that I need an authentication token to create my Retrofit service. I currently use an Observable to obtain said token, causing a rather ugly Observable construct:

```
Observable<MyService> observable = application.getMyService();
    observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(application.defaultSubscribeScheduler())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyService>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error creating service: ", e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(MyService myService) {
                    subscription = myService.searchStuff(searchFor)
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribeOn(application.defaultSubscribeScheduler())
                            .subscribe(new Subscriber<AResponseWrapper>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted() {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Error loading stuff: ", error);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNext(AResponseWrapper wrapper) {
                                    MainPresenter.this.stuff = wrapper.getStuff();
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
```

I can't help but feel that this is not how it should be done. Am I right?

Comment: you might find this answer useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28406931/5036979

Comment: @AhmedAshrafG perfect, thanks! I previously only looked at the accepted answer on that question, which confused me because of using Maps, it made me assume that flatMap is only useful when working with Maps.

Answer (score 1):

The `Observable.flatMap` is what I was looking for.
It allows mapping the result to another observable:

```
Observable<MyService> observable = application.getMyService();
    subscription = observable
            .observeOn(application.defaultSubscribeScheduler())
            .subscribeOn(application.defaultSubscribeScheduler())
            .flatMap(service -> service.searchStuff(searchFor))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<AResponseWrapper>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    if (series.size() < 1) {
                        mainView.showMessage(R.string.no_stuff_found);
                    } else {
                        mainView.showStuff(stuff);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error loading stuff: ", error);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(AResponseWrapper wrapper) {
                    MainPresenter.this.stuff= wrapper.getStuff();
                }
            });
```

Note that I first observe on the IO Scheduler and only after the flatMap I'll subscribe on the main thread. Otherwise the `service.searchStuff` call (at least I think it's that part) would be executed on the Main thread, yielding a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Thanks to @ahmed-ashraf-g who pointed me to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406931/5036979).