# Call service only if preceding observable succeeded

Tags: retrofit, observable, rx-java, rx-android

**Background**

I am just diving into the concept of RX for java. Frankly, I don't get it. In my project I use retrofit library for calling services. Currently, I have implemented all the services using callback. If I want to orchestrate service calls I have to call callbacks in callbacks which leads to quite a confusing code.

**Problem**

For the following two services I would like to call service B iff service A completed successfully using the Observables approach.

```
public interface RetrofitRestService {

    @GET("...")
    Observable<Object> A();

    @GET("...")
    Observable<Object> B();
}
```

I was searching for [Observable operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html)  I could use for my task but without any luck. I can imagine an operator like this:

```
RetrofitRestServices service;
service.A().ifSuccessfull(B());

//OR
service.A().ifWasNotEmpty(B());

//OR
service.A().useCondition(new Condition(){ ... }, B());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call A, then call B, you can use the operator `concat` : B will be called if A is completed.

```
service.A().concatWith(service.B()).subscribe();
```

But if A return `null`, B will be called.

If it's the case, then this anwser will be better : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28685808/476690

**EDIT after comment**

If you want to use the result of `A()` then `flatMap` operator is what you need

```
service.A().flatMap(resultOfA -> service.B(resultOfA)).subscribe();
```

(giving `resultOfA` as an argument of `B()` is just an example of use)

**Another way :**

You can build a result too from the response of A, and the response of B

```
service.A().flatMap(resultOfA -> service.B().zipWith(Observable.just(resultOfA), (a, b) -> new ResultOf(a, b))).subscribe();
```

`zip`operator will build a result with the result of A and B, in this case. `ResultOf` is just an example class to show how to build a result with the result of A and B.

More info on `flapMap` : [When do you use map vs flatMap in RxJava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847105/when-do-you-use-map-vs-flatmap-in-rxjava/22941881#22941881)

Comment: I am going to try it this afternoon. How can I work with the result of A() and then use "concatWith"? I have to process the result of A(). If it is a longer solution please add an edit to your answer.

Comment: The new info looks great. I still haven't make it home. But can't wait to check it out. I believe it will work. Just one more thing... In Android we still use Java 6, no closures there. How would you write down "service.A().flatMap(resultOfA -> service.B(resultOfA)).subscribe();" in Java 6. I mean particularly "resultOfA -> ... ".

Comment: You can't, out of the box. But you can try retrolambda ( gradle plugin : https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda ). It convert lambda to anonymous class. I used it on a small android project. But some people have some issues with it (with proguad, I presume)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
service.A().isEmpty().filter(new Func1<Boolean, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(Boolean empty) {
        return !empty;
    }
})
.flatMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<? extends Object>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<? extends Integer> call(Boolean empty) {
        return B();
    }
});
```

The `isEmpty` operator will emit a boolean value, which will be true only if A() doesn't emit anything. That's why if A() emits an item, the filter checking if the result of `isEmpty` will pass and the `flatMap` will be invoked, thus invoking B().

Comment: I am going to try it this afternoon. How can I work with the result of A() and then use "flatMap"? I have to process the result of A(). If it is a longer solution please add an edit to your answer.

Comment: Hmm if you need the actual result of A(), you can either cache it and then use the above logic to trigger B(), or if B uses the result of A() use the answer provided by dwursteisen.
As it seem, you need something similar to the code provided by him, that's why I'm putting +1 on his answer.

Comment: Thx Meddle, your answer helped me to understand observables more.