# RxJava, Retrofit - changing the response into ArrayAdapter item object?

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm playing with RxJava in Android. 
I'm trying to get the response of places from the server. Everything works fine:

Here is my Retrofit interface:

```
@GET("/some/path")
Observable<Response> search(@QueryMap Map map);
```

Here is how I handle this:

```
    endpointService.search(requestMap)
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                L.e(TAG, "problems");
                return null;
            })
            .subscribe(rxBus::send);
```

As you may see, I post a event (RxBus) to interested parties, in this case, a fragment:

```
    rxBus.register(Response.class)
            .subscribe(event -> {
                L.d(TAG, "Received search response");
            });
```

For now it works. I'm not shure, this "idea" of handling REST calls won't finish in a disaster (I'm new into RxJava), but for now it looks allright...

Anyways - this response is huge. I only need a list of names and addresses. And this response gives me a huuuge JSON with a lot of additional data.

My idea is to change this with `map` (or `flatMap`, I still have problems with knowing the difference). 
I've implemented something like

```
    .map(event -> {
             List<SearchItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
             for (Response r : event.getItems) {
                  list.add(new Item(r.getName, r.getAddress));
              }
                 return list;
            }
         )
```

And it works, however I'm not sure if foreach-ing isn't a bit too "oldschool". IDE says that I cant use `collect call` however I've never used it, and the autocorrection makes things even worse :)

So - am I handling this whole thing in a right way?

EDIT:

I modified my code:

```
rxBus.register(Response.class)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(event -> event.getResponse().getList())
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .map(v -> new SearchItem(v.getName(), v.getAddress())
            .toList()
            .subscribe(event -> {
                L.w(TAG, "Stuff happens");
            });
```

I have no idea what happened, but this code no longer works. Well - kinda. Without `.toList()` it launches that Log a number of times. However with - nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What would *not* work if you just initialilzed your `ArrayAdapter` with the return value of `event.getItems()`? Regarding `flatMap` vs. `map` - you *can* alway use `flatMap` where you could use `map` (just with a different `Func1`), but the reverse is not true. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847105/when-do-you-use-map-vs-flatmap-in-rxjava https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2y8exc/what_is_the_difference_between_map_and_flatmap_in/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830063/call-a-function-after-retrofix-and-rxjava-completes/33860711#33860711

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just now saw that you are creating new `Item`s inside the loop... nevermind. In that case, what you are doing is fine, I think. You **could** however, go Rx all the way and (1) `map` the `List<Response>` out of the event, (2) use `flatMap` to transform the `Observable<List<Response>>` to an `Observable<Response>`, and (3) `map` each of them to an `Item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the general approach is fine. You can slightly improve the handling of items by something like:

```java
...
.map(Event::getItems)
.flatMap(Observable::from)
.map(response -> new Item(response.getName(), response.getAddress()))
.toList()
...
```

I assume you use retrolambda. In this case what the IDE suggests ("collect") is to apply Java 8 Streams API syntax to the for-loop, which won't work in Android.

**EDIT**

I didn't realize the first option wouldn't work for the hot observable case that never emits `onCompleted` event, which is requiered by `toList()` operator to know when to stop assembling the list.

Thanks to @david.mihola, there's a different option for this case:

```java
...
.flatMap(event -> Observable.from(event.getResponse().getList())
                            .map(item -> new SearchItem(v.getName(), v.getAddress()))
                            .toList())
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about something like that, but I newer knew about `.toList()` :)

Comment: Well, I managed to do something wrong, and this code no longer works. I have no idea why, I have edited my post.

Comment: @a_dzik I just realized in your case `onCompleted` event never comes through `rxBus` and `toList()` needs this terminal event to know when to stop collecting items. Right now it adds up to the list infinitely.

Comment: Well... probably. How should I handle it?

Comment: You could try putting the `Observable.from(event.getResponse().getList()).map(...).toList()` inside the first `map` - that should make sure that *one `Event`* is mapped to *one `List<Item>`* .

Comment: @david.mihola thank you, only we'll need `flatMap` instead. I'll modify the answer

Comment: @AndroidEx - now works like a charm, however with small fix on my side - I had to cast `item` to that `ResponseItem` in order to make it see `.getName()` and such :)

Comment: @a_dzik oh, probably the compiler wasn't able to figure out generics in this case. Another way to handle this issue is to call `Observable.from` like `Observable.<ResponseItem>from(...)`

Comment: @AndroidEx: Yeah, of course `flatMap` - though a `map` with `toList().toBlocking().first()` should also work, I think.