# Combine Swing event observables with other observables

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a label which displays error messages. If you double click on it you get a big dialog showing the whole stack trace. I have two observables: One for the errors and one for the click events:

```
final ConnectableObservable<Notification> errorNotifications = pm
    .getNotificationObservable()
    .filter(notification -> notification.getType().isError() && !notification.getLongMessage().isEmpty())
    .replay(1);

errorNotifications.connect();

SwingObservable.fromMouseEvents(dialog.getMessagePanel().getMessageLabel())
               .map(MouseEvent::getClickCount)
               .filter(number -> number >= 2)
               .subscribe(integer -> errorNotifications
                   .take(1)
                   .subscribe(notification -> ErrorDialog.showError(dialog.getFrame(), "Error", notification.getLongMessage())));
```

I filter the notification observable to only show erros and replay the last error if I subscribe from it from inside my click observable.

Now my question is, are there any operators in RxJava by which I can do this more... neatly? I tried to use `combineLatest()` but this had the effect, that every time an error ocured the dialog would open.

In a more abstract way: I have two observables, one is like the "master": If the master observable (click observable) emits an item, the other observable (my error notifications) should emit the latest item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using another `Observable` in a subscription is often a design flaw.

You may check the `flatMap` operator in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847105/when-do-you-use-map-vs-flatmap-in-rxjava/22941881#22941881). It will help you to emits error notification when you emit another event.

For example, if you want to use `flatMap` operator with your code, it can be updated like this :

```
 final ConnectableObservable<Notification> errorNotifications = 
                                                  pm.getNotificationObservable()
                                                    .filter(notification -> notification.getType().isError() && !notification.getLongMessage().isEmpty())
                                                    .replay(1);

errorNotifications.connect();

SwingObservable.fromMouseEvents(dialog.getMessagePanel().getMessageLabel())
           .map(MouseEvent::getClickCount)
           .filter(number -> number >= 2)
           .flatMap(integer -> errorNotifications.take(1))
           .subscribe(notification -> ErrorDialog.showError(dialog.getFrame(), "Error", notification.getLongMessage())));
```

Comment: flatMap seems to work, but I'm not sure if I understand the underlying tech: So a ReplaySubject will emit the last item on subscrption which means that flatMap() also subscribes to the resulting observable from the passed mapping function...?

Comment: flatMap will merge all result from observables that your lambda return. So with a Replaysubject, you'll be notified of the last events, and the subsequent events too. With the take operator, you'll be notified, each times, only of the last events.