# What method should be called instead of subscribe in rxjs after flatMaps when there is no stream to be passed through?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a method takes it part of form management and does the things below. I can solve a case like this with promises easily, but here is the time to learn observables! So, the tasks of the method:

- calls `clientWebApiService.getClients()` to get clients list, and returns observable of `environmentWebApiService.getEnvironmentsNotInPipeline()`
- in the second flatMap the result will be passed to local variable
- in the `subscribe` I would like to map a data structure another to be able to setup things of a form

The `subscribe()` throws the error below:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:73)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:130)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:127)
```

I already (hopefully) figured out that subscribe expects a stream which is not provided here. If I see correctly the second flatMap should return an Observable which is processed by the `subscribe()`. In this structure there will be no. In this case what method should be called? I found the rxjs [documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc/api) with lot of methods. I don't know which one I'm looking for.

I have tried to restructure my code, but if there is no `subscribe()`, then there is no execution.

- what is the best practice case like this?

```js
public editHandler({ dataItem }): void {

        let clients: IClientContract[];
        let environments: IEnvironmentContract[];

        this.clientWebApiService.getClients()
            .flatMap((clientsResult: any): Observable<IEnvironmentContract[]> => {
                clients = clientsResult as IClientContract[];
                console.log('1', clients);
                return this.environmentWebApiService.getEnvironmentsNotInPipeline();
            })
            .flatMap((environmentResult: IEnvironmentContract[]): any => {
                environments = environmentResult;
                console.log('2', environments);
            })
            .subscribe(() => {
                console.log('3');
                let editableDeploymentItem: IDeployableEnvironmentForm = this.deployableEnvironmentContractMapperService
                    .mapDeployableEnvironmentContractToDeployableEnvironmentForm(
                    dataItem,
                    clients,
                    environments);
                console.log('4', editableDeploymentItem);

                this.editDeployment = editableDeploymentItem;
                this.isNew = false;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `do`. `do` operator just performs an action and continues the steam. In your case, I dont see why you need another operator as it can be done in the `subscribe` method itself.

You can just do :

```
public editHandler({ dataItem }): void {

        let clients: IClientContract[];
        let environments: IEnvironmentContract[];

        this.clientWebApiService.getClients()
            .flatMap((clientsResult: any): Observable<IEnvironmentContract[]> => {
                clients = clientsResult as IClientContract[];
                console.log('1', clients);
                return this.environmentWebApiService.getEnvironmentsNotInPipeline();
            })
            .subscribe((environmentResult: IEnvironmentContract[]): any => {
                environments = environmentResult;
                console.log('2', environments);
                console.log('3');
                let editableDeploymentItem: IDeployableEnvironmentForm = this.deployableEnvironmentContractMapperService
                    .mapDeployableEnvironmentContractToDeployableEnvironmentForm(
                    dataItem,
                    clients,
                    environments);
                console.log('4', editableDeploymentItem);

                this.editDeployment = editableDeploymentItem;
                this.isNew = false;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead using `this.clientWebApiService.getClients().flatMap(() => {})`
Could you give it a try by useing `this.clientWebApiService.getClients().map(() => {})`?

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847105/when-do-you-use-map-vs-flatmap-in-rxjava) may help