# map vs flatMap in reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've found a lot of answers regarding [RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847105/when-do-you-use-map-vs-flatmap-in-rxjava), but I want to understand how it works in Reactor.

My current understanding is very vague, i tend to think of map as being synchronous and flatMap to be asynchronous but I can't really get my had around it.

Here is an example:

```
files.flatMap { it ->
    Mono.just(Paths.get(UPLOAD_ROOT, it.filename()).toFile())
        .map {destFile ->
            destFile.createNewFile()
            destFile    
        }               
        .flatMap(it::transferTo)
}.then()
```

I have files (a `Flux<FilePart>`) and i want to copy it to some `UPLOAD_ROOT` on the server.

This example is taken from a book.

I can change all the `.map` to `.flatMap` and vice versa and everything still works. I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your actual question? To which methods you are actually referring to, there are multiple `map` and `flatMap` methods in Java.

Comment: I'm talking about the Reactor project. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html

Comment: Yeah, now please be more specific about the question. Where exactly you have difficulties understanding it? Why doesn't taking a look at the source code and the documentation clear the confusion? Is there something specific you don't get?

Comment: I understand from the docs that both are ways to iterate over a given Flux and that `map` is synchronous and `flatMap` is not. But I also understand that the function i give into `map` is executed async and I don't know when to use which one.

Comment: ... i'll update with a concrete example.

Comment: I did update the sample ...

Comment: you mention finding a lot of answers regarding RxJava. Note that this is the exact same concept as in RxJava

Comment: Add a tag `kotlin` probably? Since your example is in this language and not in Java?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

- `map` is for synchronous, non-blocking, 1-to-1 transformations
- `flatMap` is for asynchronous (non-blocking) 1-to-N transformations

The difference is visible in the method signature:

- `map` takes a `Function<T, U>` and returns a `Flux<U>`
- `flatMap` takes a `Function<T, Publisher<V>>` and returns a `Flux<V>`

That's the major hint: you *can* pass a `Function<T, Publisher<V>>` to a `map`, but it wouldn't know what to do with the `Publishers`, and that would result in a `Flux<Publisher<V>>`, a sequence of inert publishers.

On the other hand, `flatMap` expects a `Publisher<V>` for each `T`. It knows what to do with it: subscribe to it and propagate its elements in the output sequence. As a result, the return type is `Flux<V>`: `flatMap` will flatten each inner `Publisher<V>` into the output sequence of *all* the `V`s.

**About the 1-N aspect:**

for each `<T>` input element, `flatMap` maps it to a `Publisher<V>`. In some cases (eg. an HTTP request), that publisher will emit only one item, in which case we're pretty close to an async `map`.

But that's the degenerate case. The generic case is that a `Publisher` can emit multiple elements, and `flatMap` works just as well.

For an example, imagine you have a reactive database and you flatMap from a sequence of user IDs, with a request that returns a user's set of `Badge`. You end up with a single `Flux<Badge>` of all the badges of all these users.

**Is `map` really synchronous and *non-blocking*?**

Yes: it is synchronous in the way the operator applies it (a simple method call, and then the operator emits the result) and non-blocking in the sense that the function itself shouldn't block the operator calling it. In other terms it shouldn't introduce latency. That's because a `Flux` is still asynchronous as a whole. If it blocks mid-sequence, it will impact the rest of the `Flux` processing, or even other `Flux`.

If your map function is blocking/introduces latency but cannot be converted to return a `Publisher`, consider `publishOn`/`subscribeOn` to offset that blocking work on a separate thread.

Comment: you meant map is `blocking`, right? I also don't get the `1-to-N` really. Can you give an example when one is useful over the other? I understand that i use flatMap when I expect the result to be asynchronous, because it flattens the publishers once the result is there - is that correct?

Comment: no, map function should be non-blocking (unless you also offset the work on a separate thread using `publishOn`/`subscribeOn`). that is, it is executed synchronously but shouldn't have latency. flatMap function is asynchronous and indeed the operator flatten the results as they become available

Comment: edited the answer to explain both these aspects + flatMap 1-N example

Comment: Is this answer out of date? I think what you're calling flatMap is now "flatMapMany", and flatMap does something different -- https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/516

Comment: Just that Mono now has the added subtlety of having both flatMap (async 1 to 1 transformation) and flatMapMany (async 1 to n)

Answer (score 11):

The flatMap method is similar to the map method with the key difference that the supplier you provide to it should return a `Mono<T>` or  `Flux<T>`.

Using the map method would result in a `Mono<Mono<T>>`
whereas using flatMap results in a `Mono<T>`.

For example, it is useful when you have to make a network call to retrieve data, with a java API that returns a Mono, and then another network call that needs the result of the first one.

```java
// Signature of the HttpClient.get method
Mono<JsonObject> get(String url);

// The two urls to call
String firstUserUrl = "my-api/first-user";
String userDetailsUrl = "my-api/users/details/"; // needs the id at the end

// Example with map
Mono<Mono<JsonObject>> result = HttpClient.get(firstUserUrl).
  map(user -> HttpClient.get(userDetailsUrl + user.getId()));
// This results with a Mono<Mono<...>> because HttpClient.get(...)
// returns a Mono

// Same example with flatMap
Mono<JsonObject> bestResult = HttpClient.get(firstUserUrl).
  flatMap(user -> HttpClient.get(userDetailsUrl + user.getId()));
// Now the result has the type we expected
```

Also, it allows for handling errors precisely:

```java
public UserApi {
  
  private HttpClient httpClient;
    
  Mono<User> findUser(String username) {
    String queryUrl = "http://my-api-address/users/" + username;
    
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> httpClient.get(queryUrl)).
      flatMap(response -> {
        if (response.statusCode == 404) return Mono.error(new NotFoundException("User " + username + " not found"));
        else if (response.statusCode == 500) return Mono.error(new InternalServerErrorException());
        else if (response.statusCode != 200) return Mono.error(new Exception("Unknown error calling my-api"));
        return Mono.just(response.data);
      });
  }
                                           
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## How map internally works in the Reactor.

[image: How MAP internally works]

Creating a `Player` class.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Player {
        String name;
        String name;
}
```

Now creating some instances of `Player` class

```
Flux<Player> players = Flux.just(
        "Zahid Khan",
        "Arif Khan",
        "Obaid Sheikh")
        .map(fullname -> {
            String[] split = fullname.split("\\s");
            return new Player(split[0], split[1]);
        });

StepVerifier.create(players)
          .expectNext(new Player("Zahid", "Khan"))
          .expectNext(new Player("Arif", "Khan"))
          .expectNext(new Player("Obaid", "Sheikh"))
          .verifyComplete();
```

> What’s important to understand about the map() is that the mapping is
> performed synchronously, as each item is published by the source Flux.
> If you want to perform the mapping asynchronously, you should consider
> the flatMap() operation.

## How FlatMap internally works.

[image: How FlatMap internally works.]

```
Flux<Player> players = Flux.just(
      "Zahid Khan", 
      "Arif Khan", 
      "Obaid Sheikh")
      .flatMap(
            fullname -> 
                  Mono.just(fullname).map(p -> {
                        String[] split = p.split("\\s");
                        return new Player(split[0], split[1]);
        }).subscribeOn(Scheduler.parallel()));

        List<Player> playerList = Arrays.asList(
                  new Player("Zahid", "Khan"),
                  new Player("Arif", "Khan"), 
                  new Player("Obaid", "Sheikh"));

        StepVerifier.create(players).expectNextMatches(player ->         
                playerList.contains(player))    
                        .expectNextMatches(player ->  
                                playerList.contains(player))
                        .expectNextMatches(player -> 
                                playerList.contains(player))
                        .expectNextMatches(player -> 
                                playerList.contains(player))
                        .verifyComplete();
```

Internally in a Flatmap(), a map() operation is performed to the Mono to transform the String to Player. Furthermore, **subcribeOn () indicates that each subscription should take place in a parallel thread.** **In absence of subscribeOn() flatmap() acts as a synchronized.**

The map is for synchronous, non-blocking, one-to-one transformations
while the flatMap is for asynchronous (non-blocking) One-to-Many transformations.

Comment: Based on the  picture In your flatmap example it is possible to have different amount of input and output elements. Could you please provide example ? because in your example you have equal amount (3 input elements and 3 output) elements.

Comment: Good answer, but please if you quote sth, indicate the source. Yours are from spring-in-action-fifth-edition