# Find a particular record and update

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Find a particular record and update

```
studentRepository.findByStudid(studId).log().map(existingStud -> {
                                            return studentRepository.save(existingStud); // This return Mono defer ??
                                        }).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.flatMap` instead of `.map` operator.
It will subscribe to the inner Mono returned from `save`.

See [map vs flatMap in reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115135/map-vs-flatmap-in-reactor)

Comment: Thank you flatMap works - inner Mono was a new thing i learned.