# How can avoid breaking request flow in WebFilter when returning from inside another Mono<Object>>?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Here's some ridiculous code for example

```
@Component
public final class ReCaptchaCheckWebFilter implements WebFilter {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return Mono.just("foo").map(s -> chain.filter(exchange)).then();
  }
}
```

With this webfiler, the request never reaches my Controller. It does return a 200 http status code.

If I found myself needing to return from inside another Mono<Object>, how do I do that while forwarding the request along the filter chain and onto the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chain.filter` return a Mono, but in your example it is not a part of the stream (nothing subscribes to it). To fix that, use should use [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method

```
    return Mono.just("foo").flatMap(s -> chain.filter(exchange));
```

Comment: This is the answer, but can you help explain it further? I've read that `.map()` is synchronous while `.flatMap()` is asynchronous but not sure why that matters here. And are you suggesting if I followed my `.map()` with a `.subscribe*()`, it would work?

Comment: No, in webflux application you should (almost) never use `subscribe` method, but you should remember that Mono/Flux does not execute without subscription  (just like creating a thread and not starting it). Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115135/map-vs-flatmap-in-reactor for more details