# How to convert Mono object to other Mono object in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a class like this

```java
public class Person {
      private String name;
      private String age;
      private Boolean student;
      ...
      //
      getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class PersonDto {
      private List<Person> persons
      private Person president
      //
      getters and setters
}
```

and get data to webclient from external API

```java
--- omitted ---
final Mono<PersonDto> personDto = wrapperWebClient.getPersonDto(uriComponents, params, PersonDto.class);
Mono<StudentDto> studentDto = convert(personDto);
--- omitted ---
```

and I want to transform data Mono DTO like below.

```java
public class Student {
      // no constructors 
      private String name;
      private String age;
      private Boolean student;
      ...
      //
      getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class StudentDto {
      private List<Student> students;
      private Student represent;
      ...
      //
      getters and setters
}
```

it's my try

```java
--- omitted ---
private Mono<StudentDto> convert(Mono<PersonDto> personDto) {
      StudentDto studentDto = new StudentDto();
      personDto.map(
          persons -> {
              studentDto.setStudents(
                      persons.getPersons()
                       .stream().filter(person -> person.isStudent())
                       .collect(toList())
              );
              studentDto.setRepresent(
                      persons.getRepresent().isStudent()
              );
          }
      )
      return ???;
}
```

My approach seems to be synchronous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map vs flatMap in reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115135/map-vs-flatmap-in-reactor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return `Mono` with map

```
private Mono<StudentDto> convert(Mono<PersonDto> personDto) {
      return personDto.map(
          persons -> {
              StudentDto studentDto = new StudentDto();
              studentDto.setStudents(
                      persons.getPersons()
                       .stream().filter(person -> person.isStudent())
                       .collect(toList())
              );
              studentDto.setRepresent(
                      persons.getRepresent().isStudent()
              );
          }
      );
}
```

The main difference between `map` and `flatMap` is **synchronicity**.

If you want handle another asynchronous one, use `flatMap`.

Or, if you just want to reformat the output of the `Mono/Flux`, use `map`.

Answer (score 0):

you use `flatMap`. This is basic reactor and you should read through the [Getting started reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#getting-started) before asking on stack overflow.

```
private Mono<StudentDto> convert(Mono<PersonDto> personDto) {
    return personDto.flatMap(personDto -> {
                final StudentDto studentDto = new StudentDto();
                studentDto.setStudents(
                        persons.getPersons()
                         .stream().filter(person -> person.isStudent())
                         .collect(toList())
                );
                studentDto.setRepresent(
                        persons.getRepresent().isStudent()
                );
                return Mono.just(studentDto);
            })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `transform` method in **Mono** class.

```
return Mono.fromFuture(step1.callFuture(input))
           .doOnSuccess(this::logJsonInput)
           .transform(otherService::calculate);
```

where

```
OtherService {
   public Mono<Result> calculate(Mono<Step1Output> input) {
        //...
   }       
}
```