# Webflux upload file not saving

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I have this piece of code:

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/store"})
public Mono<ResponseEntity<StoreResponse>> store(@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> file,
                                                 @RequestPart("publicationId") String publicationId,
                                                 @RequestPart("visible") String visible) throws Exception {
    return file
            .doOnNext(this::checkFile)
            .flatMap((f) -> this.saveFileToDatabase(UUID.fromString(publicationId),
                    f.filename(),
                    Boolean.parseBoolean(visible)))
            .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().body(new StoreResponse("", "", "Working",
                    null))))
            .onErrorReturn(ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body(new StoreResponse("Not Working",
                    "", "Working", null)));
}
```

**Question 1:**
Strange thing with this is that this works as long as i use `flatMap` on the `Mono`.
When i switch to `map` instead of `flatMap` then it does not work (the file will not be written to a database `this.saveFileToDatabase` (via spring-data-r2dbc)).
Why is this the way it is?

**Question 2:**
When i want to do another operation (save file to a minio container) after the saving to database - how can i chain this into the given code? Another `then()`?

Comment: Best use for `.then` is if you get a `Mono` of type `void` back as far as I know, maybe you confuse it with promises if you know that. your code could be the following (without your questions, these are answered in the answer below)
`.flatMap(...).map(unused -> ResponseEntity.ok()...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I switch to map instead of flatMap then it does not work

`map` operator is designed to perform 1 to 1 **synchronous** operations like a simple object mapping. On the other hand, `flatMap` is used for asynchronous I/O operations like as in your case. See [map vs flatMap in Reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49115135/8909235)

> When i want to do another operation after the saving to database

You could use a second `flatmap` like this:

```java
 .flatMap(file -> this.saveFileToDatabase(...).map(reponse -> file))
 .flatMap(file -> this.saveFileToContainer(...))
```

Comment: Thank you. I know `map` and `flatMap` from Java 8 Streams. So this behaviour is a bit confusing to me.