# Returning an error changes method signature

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

I had a sense from tutorials that returning a throwable, shouldn't change method return type.

Here are my tries:

1. When using `handle`, everything is fine until I add `.timeout()`, then function return type is changed to `Flux<Object>`

```java
private Flux<String> exampleHandle()
{
    MutableHttpRequest<String> req = HttpRequest.GET("http://localhost:8080");

    return httpClient.exchange(req, TokenResponse.class)
        .handle((response, sink) -> {
            Optional<TokenResponse> optionalBody = response.getBody();
            if (optionalBody.isEmpty()) {
                sink.error(new InitializationException("Failed to fetch authentication token. Body is null."));
            } else {
                TokenResponse tokenResponse = optionalBody.get();
                String accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
                if (accessToken != null) {
                    sink.next(accessToken);
                } else {
                    sink.error(new InitializationException("Failed to fetch authentication token. Authentication token is null."));
                }
            }
        });
       // .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)); // Timeout changes return type to Flux<Object>
}
```

2. When using `map` and `Flux.error` (i tried `Mono.error` also), function return type is changed to `Flux<Object>` when I introduce `Flux.error` in `map`

```java
private Flux<String> exampleMap()
{
    MutableHttpRequest<String> req = HttpRequest.GET("http://localhost:8080");

    return httpClient.exchange(req, TokenResponse.class)
        .map(response -> {
            Optional<TokenResponse> optionalBody = response.getBody();
            if (optionalBody.isEmpty()) {
                return Flux.error(new InitializationException("Failed to fetch authentication token. Body is null."));
            } else {
                TokenResponse tokenResponse = optionalBody.get();
                String accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
                if (accessToken != null) {
                    return accessToken;
                } else {
                    return Flux.error(new InitializationException("Failed to fetch authentication token. Authentication token is null."));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Can someone more knowledgeable explain me what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: If your Flux times out, then it cannot return a string, I guess that's why it changes to Object. When you map, you shouldn't return the container type (that's what flatMap is for)

Comment: Are you confusing _throwing_ an `Exception` with returning it? They're not the same thing.  When you return something from a method, control is passed to the method that called your one.  When you throw something, control is passed to a `catch` clause, which might be several steps down the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You should move `timeout` before `handle`:

```java
 return httpClient.exchange(req, TokenResponse.class)
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .handle((response, sink) -> {
```

As for the `map` case, take a look at the method signature:

[Flux map(Function<? super T,? extends V> mapper)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

`map` takes a `Function<T, U>` and returns a `Flux<U>`, returning `Flux.error` is invalid. You could simply use `throw` inside `map` and Reactor will turn it into a proper error signal **but** I think `handle` fits better in this case.

Useful links:

- [Correct way of throwing exceptions with Reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595420/correct-way-of-throwing-exceptions-with-reactor)
- [map vs flatMap in reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115135/map-vs-flatmap-in-reactor)