# How to convert Mono object without blocking?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, reactor

Suppose I have this method:

```
public static Mono<String> getData2() {
    return Mono.just("7");
}
```

I want to call this method, get back the string, convert that string to an Integer 7, and then return that integer in a **non-blocking way**. How can I do this?

I've tried this, but the `map` function is blocking (synchronous):

```
public static Mono<Integer> getData1() {
    return getData2().map(data -> Integer.parseInt(data));
}
```

I tried using `flatMap` instead (asynchronous):

```
public static Mono<Integer> getData1() {
    return getData2().flatMap(data -> Integer.parseInt(data));
}
```

But then I get this error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Mono<? extends Integer>`

So what can I do?

Comment: Calling `map` on a `Mono` is not a synchronous, blocking call. What makes you think that it is?

Comment: @Jesper Well, I'm not so sure of the terminology. Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115135/map-vs-flatmap-in-reactor , synchronous is different from non-blocking.

Comment: The accepted answer on that question explains that `map` is a non-blocking operation.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring-reactor, operations, such as `Mono.just`, `Mono.map` and so on, are lazy evaluation. Nothing happens until `subscribe`.
Blocking usually occurs in network calling or resource locking. It's another concept.
If you want a asynchronous `Mono`, `Mono.defer` may be help. And `subscribeOn` can be used to do resource isolation.

Back to the question, `Mono.just("7").map(Integer::parseInt)` just gives you a mono object. In asynchronous way, we can change this to `Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just("7").map(Integer::parseInt))subscribeOn(Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(xxxx))`. But this may be unnecessary and meanless.