# map vs. flatMap with Mono.fromSupplier for long-running operations

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm using Project Reactor as part of a project using Spring WebFlux and learned that `Flux.map` should only be used for "simple" operations. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/49169314/947526:

> - `map` is for synchronous, non-blocking, 1-to-1 transformations
> - `flatMap` is for asynchronous (non-blocking) 1-to-N transformations

In my understanding, something like `fluxOfStrings.map(String::toUpperCase)` is fine, but `flux.map(this::computeStuff)` is not (assuming `computeStuff` takes a considerable amount of time).

However, I fail to understand how (and if) I can use `flatMap` to improve my code. Based on the example above, I could write

```
fluxOfSomething.flatMap(value ->
    Mono.fromSupplier(
        () -> computeStuff(value)
    )
)
```

Is this better, in any sense? If so, how can I see the improvement using a simple test? If not, what can I do to trigger `computeStuff` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to see when to use each:

#### For computationally expensive tasks

If your `computeStuff` fun is just computationally expensive and doesn't involve any I/O, you could use either `map` or `flatMap` based on how you manage threads. If you're okay with the operation running on the same thread (typically, the event loop), `map` is fine too. If you want to offload it to another thread, you'll need to wrap it in a `Mono.fromSupplier` and use `flatMap` instead, as the SOF answer suggested.

#### For I/O-bound or blocking tasks

If `computeStuff` does I/O or any blocking operation, you *definitely* should not use `map`. Instead, you may need to offload this to another thread. `flatMap` becomes useful here because you're typically returning a `Mono` or `Flux` which represents the result of an async operation.

---

In your example:

```java
fluxOfSomething.flatMap(value ->
    Mono.fromSupplier(
        () -> computeStuff(value)
    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) 
)
```

You're using `flatMap` cause you're returning a `Mono` from the function. The combination of `Mono.fromSupplier` and `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` (I added this) ensures that the `computeStuff` fun runs in another thread, not blocking the main reactive thread, which is generally recommended.

---

#### To notice a difference:

- Blocking Scenario: If `computeStuff` is a blocking operation and you use `map`, you'll quickly see issues when you put your service under load. The main reactive thread will get blocked, leading to a significant degradation in performance;
- Async Scenario: If you use `flatMap` and offload the work to another thread, under the same load, you should see better performance since the main reactive thread isn't blocked;
- Simple Transformations: Simple transformations that don't block or aren't computationally intensive, there would be a negligible performance difference between using `map` & `flatMap`

---

Let's try to write some dummy test now.

- Prerequisites:
  Let's imagine that you've already set up the two endpoints (/map and /flatMap) and some `blockingOperation` (computeStuff) method

We may write something like:

```java
@Test
public void testMapVsFlatMap() {
    long startMap = System.currentTimeMillis();
    webTestClient.get().uri("/map")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBodyList(String.class);
    long endMap = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long startFlatMap = System.currentTimeMillis();
    webTestClient.get().uri("/flatMap")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBodyList(String.class);
    long endFlatMap = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // flatMap is indeed faster than map for our simulated blocking OP
    assertTrue((endFlatMap - startFlatMap) < (endMap - startMap));
}
```