# rxjava: difference between flatmap and map

Tags: java, rx-java

I would like to know if there is any difference in the behavior between those both methods or if it's just a matter of style:

```
private Single<JsonObject> foo() {
     return Single.just(new JsonObject()).flatMap(next -> Single.just(next));
}

private Single<JsonObject> bar() {
     return Single.just(new JsonObject()).map(next -> next);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use map vs flatMap in RxJava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847105/when-do-you-use-map-vs-flatmap-in-rxjava)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in behavior as both are pointless operations. The first simply repeats wrapping the object into a `Single`, while the second maps it to itself. You would never have a reason to do either.

Read up on 'flatMap()' and 'map()': the first turns each value into an observable of different values, the second turns each value into a different value.

Comment: Ok thanks and i know the methods are pointless, it was for the example!

Answer (score 0):

You can represent for your self a **flatMap** operator like a sequence of two other operator **map** and **merge**.

**Map** will convert your source item to Observable that emit a value based on the function inside of **map**. 
At this point **merge** will help to put together every item that emitted by each of your new observables, not the source one.

There is a good illustration on that book https://www.manning.com/books/rxjava-for-android-developers

[map with merge together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NF4N.png)

To simplify this code was introduced **flatMap** operator

[only flatMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XknO.png)