# RxJava/Kotlin Observable method call chain - how to terminate?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I want to implement method to edit a note, save it to local database (cache) and then send it to the server as a POST request. I am learning RxJava and I wanted to create `Observable` from the note and then apply transformations on it, like to map it to an Entity model and saving. The issue that my method returns Completable and this chain returns `Observable<Completable>`. How to unwrap the `Completable` from this `Observable` which I used only to start RxJava stuff. Each `editNote()` methods returns a `Completable`.

```
 override fun editNote(note: Note): Completable {
    return Observable.just(note)
        .map { mapper.mapToEntity(it) }
        .map { noteEntity ->
            factory.getCacheDataStore().editNote(noteEntity)
                .andThen { factory.getRemoteDataStore().editNote(noteEntity) }
        }
}
```

=======================================================

## UPDATE

Finally, I managed to find "a solution" but I am not sure it is correct :-)

```
override fun editNote(note: Note): Completable {
    return Observable.just(note)
        .map { mapper.mapToEntity(it) }
        .flatMapCompletable { noteEntity ->
            factory.getCacheDataStore().editNote(noteEntity)
                .andThen { factory.getRemoteDataStore().editNote(noteEntity) }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `flatMapCompletable` instead of `map`, because `map` just intercepts the stream and maps the emissions to another type, while 'flatMap' (or it's siblings), from the docs:

> Transform the items emitted by an Observable into Observables, then flatten the emissions from those into a single Observable.

You can see it's marble diagram in [Here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)

Comment: Could you translate that (the difference between map and flatMap) into English please? The Rx docs are written in their own language and are painfully opaque.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847105/when-do-you-use-map-vs-flatmap-in-rxjava

Maybe the usecases of each will help you understand the difference.